# django1.3 + django-formwizard + initial datas issue

Tags: python, django, django-formwizard

i am using django 1.3, with django-formwizard.
I have a WizardView with 2 ModelForms which works fine in creation mode (as_view linked in the url conf)
but i can't make it work in edit mode.
When i do in a view:

```
return MyWizard.as_view([Form1,Form2], instance_dict={0:instance1, 1:instance2})(request)
```

the wizard instance is not present in the context
if i do:

```
return MyWizard([Form1,Form2], instance_dict={0:instance1, 1:instance2})
```

i get:
    **init**() takes exactly 1 non-keyword argument (2 given)

MyWizard is very basic, it only has `get_template_names` and `done` methods.

Answer (score 0):

It appears the FormWizard constructor accepts a keyword argument named `initial` and nothing else, which is a dictionary mapping step to an initial data dict.

```
def __init__(self, form_list, initial=None):
```

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.3/ref/contrib/formtools/form-wizard/#providing-initial-data-for-the-forms

```
>>> from testapp.forms import ContactForm1, ContactForm2, ContactWizard
>>> initial = {
...     0: {'subject': 'Hello', 'sender': 'user@example.com'},
...     1: {'message': 'Hi there!'}
... }
>>> wiz = ContactWizard([ContactForm1, ContactForm2], initial=initial)
>>> form1 = wiz.get_form(0)
>>> form2 = wiz.get_form(1)
```

Comment: i already tried that, i get "init() takes exactly 1 non-keyword argument (2 given)" too

Comment: the solution:return MyWizard([Form1,Form2], instance_dict={'0':instance1, '1':instance2})